# How can i copy one bean to another bean using spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know how to copy one bean to an another using spring framework.

What configuration is required to be done in the beans.xml file for two beans

Answer (score 10):

You can use BeanUtils class. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html.

No configuration required, just invoke:

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(Object source, Object target);
```

Comment: Its for normal application. How can we do it in spring framework and what is the configuration required

Comment: BeanUtils is provided by the Spring Framework and you can use it to instantiate beans and copy the properties from source bean into target bean. If this isn't what you need, please edit the question. The more specific the question the more accurate the answer :D